# How to get GDB to show the source code while debugging?

Tags: gdb, g++

To make gdb make use of a single source file, you can store it in the same directory where gdb is run. How about a complete folder ?

E.g. I have a folder called "bootup" with multiple subfolders and files in it. It generates a binary called "bootup" which I need to debug for a crash and also to understand code flow.

If i just have the bootup folder (containing the source code) in the path it doesn't seem to be enough. When i set a breakpoint and debug it still only shows the file as follows but not the source code.

```
(gdb)directory /root/bootup
Source directories searched: /root/bootup:/root:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) n
141     in RecFns.cpp
(gdb)
142     in RecFns.cpp
```

RecFns.cpp is under /root/bootup/dir1/dir2/dir3/RecFns.cpp

What should I do to be able to get gdb printing the source file contents as I debug along.
As per http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html, directory xyz should be able to make gdb search in the directory specified. But this isn't working for me.

Comment: ¿Is your executable compiled with proper debug symbols? I never had to deal with manually supplying gdb with source code paths, they all seem to be read from debug symbols.

Comment: yes its properly compiled with debug symbols. -g -Og -UNDEBUG -rdynamic -funwind-tables

Comment: I would like it to say 
(gdb) n
141    if ( ! defaultRec && ! m_DynamicRec) { throw receiver_exception( NotImplemented ); }
(gdb) n
142     m_Resource->GetEventManager()->RegisterEventProducer( std::weak_ptr<Rec>(rec) );

Comment: You should try `-g3 -ggdb`

Comment: I usually use the [`list`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_46.html) command to show source lines.  Another technique is to open the file with an editor that shows line numbers; one window for GDB and one for the source code.

Comment: list is only giving me this -
(gdb) list 141
136     in RecFns.cpp
(gdb) list 143
138     in RecFns.cpp
(gdb)

Comment: @user7860670 As per http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html, directory xyz should be able to make gdb search in the directory specified.

Comment: This is working, but i am not sure how to get it to do recursively by itself.


(gdb) directory dir1/dir2/dir3/RecFact/
Source directories searched: /root/dir1/dir2/dir3/RecFact/:/root:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) n
149                 Rec( SrcId, Name, Loc,
(gdb) n
152                            m_eventServiceResource ));
(gdb)
154             log("finished: create recording object");
(gdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gdb `find . -type d | xargs printf " -d %s"`  prog
worked for me eventually. This supplies the directories recursively to gdb.
Found it here - https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=e61837e2-2ccc-4cce-80c8-3c8555aeacbd#gsc.tab=0

Now i am able to see the source code like how i wanted to :-)

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary on any ELF platform, where GCC automatically records compilation directory and GDB automatically searches that directory (that's what `$cdir` stands for ). Your build is borked in some way, or you have a broken GCC.

Comment: Mine is running on the arm platform. Don't know what issue i have there as I too didn't see a problem with GCC on ubuntu.